# Vaadin table header color

Tags: java, css, sass, vaadin

I have this code in .scss file:

```
  .example-table .v-table-header-cell:nth-child(2), 
    .example-table .v-table-header-cell-desc:nth-child(2) {
    background : red;
}
```

and I use it in java:

```
table.setStyleName("example-table");
```

I get second table header in red color.

**My question: How to pass argument(in this case - '2') from java to scss file, that second column header of the table would be red?**

Comment: You could try using jquery to update the style off the table cell being used as the header for your specific column.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can pass argument from java to css but you can achieve what you want by setting `CellStyleGenerator` on your table

```
table.setCellStyleGenerator(new Table.CellStyleGenerator() {
    @Override
    public String getStyle(Table source, Object itemId, Object propertyId) {
        int row = ((Integer)itemId).intValue();
        if(row == 2)
            return "red-background-style"; // will set this style to every cell in the row

        return null;
    }
});
```

See this example for more details:
https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-table.html#components.table.css.cellstylegenerator